# accessing tkinter textbox input for pyttsx3

Tags: tkinter, pyttsx3

Trying to make a little screen reader in tkinter using pyttsx3.

Here is the code first:

```py
import tkinter as tk
import pyttsx3

jabberwocky = """
’Twas brillig, and the slithy toves
      Did gyre and gimble in the wabe:
All mimsy were the borogoves,
      And the mome raths outgrabe. 
      """


def READfromCURSOR ():

    pos=text_box.index(CURRENT, END)
    engine.say(pos)
    engine.runAndWait()

    
def PAUSEREADING (): 
    
    pass


window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("800x600+100+100")
framed1 = tk.Frame(window)    

text_box = tk.Text(framed1)
text_box.pack(padx=5, pady=15)

text_box.insert(tk.INSERT, jabberwocky)
    
framed1.pack()  

b = tk.Button(window, text ="Read From Cursor", command = READfromCURSOR)
b.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

How to start reading in the middle of a bunch of text?  For example, if you look at the sample variable "jabberwocky", the text will automatically insert into the text_box at runtime.

So if then one placed the cursor after "Did gyre and gimble in the wabe:" When the button is pressed, the reader should respond, "All mimsy were the borogoves, And the mome raths outgrabe."

But the `pos=text_box.index(CURRENT, END)` command is generating the following error message:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\arnie\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "<ipython-input-27-532959af7f5a>", line 14, in READfromCURSOR
    pos=text_box.index(CURRENT, END)
NameError: name 'CURRENT' is not defined
```

Comment: Please focus on only one question at a time.

Comment: I don't see where you define or import CURRENT anywhere in your code.

Comment: I thought CURRENT must have been some kind of internal command to the text widget. Can you explain how to correct the problem?  My intuitive understanding of CURRENT was probably just where the cursor was placed.  That's not to say I was right, but I am not sure of what to do about it.

Comment: That is `INSERT`, IIRC

Answer (score 0):

The text widget has a mark named `"insert"` to represent the insertion cursor. I recommend using the raw string since that's what the literal name of the mark is. You can use the `INSERT` constant supplied by tkinter, though to me it's pointless since the constant is just the string `"insert"`.

The special index `"end"` represents the position immediately after the last character. However, this is after an implicit newline that tkinter adds to the end of the widget. If you want to get only the text entered by the user  you need to back up one character from the end. Indexes can have modifiers that adjust the index. To get all of the text minus the last newline you can use the string `"end-1c"` (end, minus one character)

Thus, to get all of the text between the insertion cursor and the end of the widget you should use this:

```
text = text_box.get("insert", "end-1c")
```

If instead of the text you want the actual text positions, you need to call the `index` on each position separately.

```
start = text_box.index("insert")
end = text_box.index("end-1c")
```